# trying to salvage overloaded mic sound

Tags: audio, microphone, audacity

I'm trying to salvage footage where apparently the mic was being overloaded (a lot).
I'm an complete audacity noob, so i'm hoping that it is fixable in some way.

When i look at it imported into audacity I can see the audio is clipping both the top and the bottom (I have no idea if this is what it is called, but again I'm new to this).

If anyone can help me with this, it would be very appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Wouter

Comment: If it's clipped off, then the data doesn't exist beyond the clipping point, so no, it's not really 'fixable' (short of re-recording) since there's no data to recover. Having said that, Audacity does have a [clip fix utility](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/clip_fix.html).  I doubt it'll help beyond Very basic clipping - have you tried that yet?

Comment: [Removing (or reducing) clipping with Audacity](http://www.hydrogenaud.io/forums/index.php?showtopic=99998)